# While loop in nightwatch.js

Tags: loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver, while-loop, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to run the following code (*a number of steps*) several times (e.g: 10 times) so that:

1. the user navigates to the detailed url
2. a random button is clicked, as per the defined var values
3. this is repeated 10 times
4. the test is then complete

I'm working with the following **NightwatchJS** code:

```
var randomEmail = faker.internet.email()
var competitionReference = ['drawing_21715','drawing_21704']
var randomCompetitionReference = competitionReference[Math.floor(Math.random()*competitionReference.length)]

module.exports = { 
  'navigate to homepage': function (browser) {        
    browser
      .url('http://clickswin-stage.bellamagazine.co.uk/') 
  },

  'select a competition': function (browser) {
    browser
      .useXpath()
        .click('//*[@id="' + randomCompetitionReference + '"]/div/div[1]')
  },
};
```

I've read that the best way to do this would be to use a **while** loop, but I'm not really sure how to set this up for my code above.

For example, if I were to use:

```
var i = 0
while ( i < 10) {
```

etc, whereabouts would I need to put this loop code within my code above?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be using a recursive function. Here is an example of how this could look like:

```
var randomEmail = faker.internet.email()
var competitionReference = ['drawing_21715', 'drawing_21704']
// var randomCompetitionReference = competitionReference[Math.floor(Math.random() * competitionReference.length)]
var randomCompetitionReference = function() {return competitionReference[Math.floor(Math.random() * competitionReference.length)]}

module.exports = { 
  'navigate to homepage': function (browser) {        
    browser
      .url('http://clickswin-stage.bellamagazine.co.uk/') 
  },

  'select a competition': function (browser, recursions) { 
    // Put the main code into a separat recursive function.
    const doClick = function(times) {
      if (times > 0) { // This is the equivalent to "while ( i < 10) {"
        return browser
          .useXpath()
          .click('//*[@id="' + randomCompetitionReference() + '"]/div/div[1]')
          .useCss()  
          .perform(()=>{ // perform() makes sure, that one function call is only executed after the other has fineshed (not concorrent)
            return doClick(times -1)
          })
      } else {
        return browser
      }
    }
    doClick(recursions)
  }
}
```

In your case you would call the function 'select a competition' with 10 as the parameter "recursions".

Note that I have changed "randomCompetitionReference" to be a function, so this generates a different value every time it is called. Else it would get one random value when its defined, and would reuse that same value for every click().

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this has become more complicated than I thought. After the URL request there is a cookie dismissal, where a button needs to be clicked. However, this only needs to be pressed on the *first iteration of the loop only*. On the 2nd iteration the cookie dismissal is not present, so shouldn't be referenced (as it correctly comes back with a 'element not found' error). So *first* iteration, get url, dismiss cookie, select competition. *second* iteration, get url, select competition. Is there a way of doing this with 'for loops'. Many thanks.

Comment: After I just read this article about the nightwatch command queue ( https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue ) I think you can just use a normal for-loop, like so: ```for ( let i = 0 ; i<10; i++) { if(i===0){do extra click} do normal click}```Nightwatch actaully takes care that the calls are executed one ofter anaother.